# Where to read about Android new API and deprecated api list

Tags: android, api, deprecated

I'm learning Android by myself mostly from online tutorial. As Android is evolving all the time, most of the old tutorial uses API which give warning that API is deprecated and should not be used.

I believe while some API is marked as deprecated then there must be new way to solve that similar problem. Is there any place where to read/find deprecated API and the alternative new API to use.

For instance I study ListView and GridView. I got good understanding for both. After a while I found both were deprecated and should be used RecyclerView. Thus it feels like waste of time for studying these  ListView and GridView. I should have study  RecyclerView only.

Planning to study Adapters. I found  ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter. I'm don't know what is deprecated and what is the new API instead of these. Are they still used in API level 22? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing Deprecated (which means the API method calls are "marked" to not be deleted in the future, and should not be used), which being replaced by newer features (as in GridView and ListView).

If the API is *Deprecated*, in most cases (when the developer is thorough) the API document itself should provide a link to the new method that should be use instead.

In other cases where the technology is old like ListView, or ActionBar (now you should use Toolbar) those technologies are not encouraged anymore, in favor of new APIs.  The important distinction is that these features are NOT deprecated, just not encouraged to be used anymore.

In case of *Deprecation* the API itself should be documented.
In case of *Replaced by newer technologies* there are a few resources worth reviewing listed here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html

Answer (score 1):

You can know everything from here. [api_diff/22/changes](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes.html)
from the offical website.

Comment: API Diff Specification
`To Level: 22`
`From Level: 21`

Answer (score 0):

The information you're looking for is available straight from Google:

- Major new releases are announced on http://android-developers.blogspot.com/.
- Release notes are available on http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/index.html

If you follow the links in the latter, one of the resources it leads to is a detailed API diff, such as mentioned in Shekar Chaudhary's answer.